# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal - if Wordpress Debug in wp-config is set to true

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, errors, wp-config, debug

To clear up my notices in my Wordpress Shop (with Woocommerce) i set WP_DEBUG to true in my Wordpress wp-config file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Now im getting the following error in my firebug Debugger Console

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

The Error points to the following script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var test_qv_localize = {"adminurl":"https:\/\/test.com    \/online-    shop\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

With Debug false the Error disapears. Any idea how to solve this issue, because it concerns me?

Comment: look the source code in your browser, you can have PHP error which not render in HTML.

Comment: I did, nothing... no notice, warning or something else...

Comment: Update your question with the php code that is printing test_qv_localize value.